# How do I make the character drag the camera when it hits the edges in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

First time posting, I can't figure out how to make the character in my game drag the camera when it hits the edge of the screen. Using clamp just stops my character from moving when hitting a certain point (not at the place I want it to). Any help would be appreciated.

```
    
import pygame, os
pygame.init()

        
SPEED = 10


SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H = 800, 600
MAP_W, MAP_H = SCREEN_W*3, SCREEN_H*3

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H))
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
back = pygame.image.load("my_image")
BACKGROUND = pygame.transform.scale(back, (MAP_W, MAP_H))

CAMERA_X1, CAMERA_Y1, CAMERA_X2, CAMERA_Y2 = 0, 0, SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H

def draw_screen(player):
    WIN.fill((255,255,255))
    WIN.blit(BACKGROUND, (CAMERA_X1, CAMERA_Y1))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (0,0,0), (player.x, player.y, 50, 50))
    pygame.display.update()


def handle_movement(pressed, player):
    global CAMERA_X1, CAMERA_Y1, CAMERA_X2, CAMERA_Y2
    if pressed[pygame.K_a]: #left
        if player.x+50 < CAMERA_X1:
            CAMERA_X1 -= SPEED*2
        else:
            player.x -= SPEED
    if pressed[pygame.K_d]: #right
        if player.x-50 > CAMERA_X2:
            CAMERA_X2 += SPEED*2
        else:
            player.x += SPEED
    if pressed[pygame.K_w]: #up
        if player.y+50 < CAMERA_Y1:
            CAMERA_Y1 -= SPEED*2
        else:
            player.y -= SPEED
    if pressed[pygame.K_s]: #down
        if player.y-50 > CAMERA_Y2:
            CAMERA_Y2 += SPEED*2
        else:
            player.y += SPEED


def main(): #Main game loop
    player = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
    running = True
    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        draw_screen(player)
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        handle_movement(keys_pressed, player)

    
    pygame.quit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm relatively new to pygame so please try to explain as thoroughly as possible :)

Comment: Related: [How to move the player across a one background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67736156/how-to-move-the-player-across-a-one-background-image?noredirect=1#comment119731761_67736156)

Answer (score 0):

So a camera is basically just an offset added to everything in the scene. Here is a
scene with just a controllable rectangle and a background and no camera.

```
import pygame, os
pygame.init()
   
SPEED = 10

SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H = 800, 600
MAP_W, MAP_H = SCREEN_W*3, SCREEN_H*3
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H))
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
BACKGROUND = pygame.Surface((MAP_W, MAP_H)).convert()

sq = pygame.Surface((50, 50)).convert()
sq.fill((255, 255, 0))
for x in range(27):
    for y in range(18):
        BACKGROUND.blit(sq, (x * 100, y * 100))
    
cameraOffset = [0 ,0]    
def draw_screen(player):
    WIN.fill((255,255,255))
    WIN.blit(BACKGROUND, (0, 0))
    playerPos = (player.x, player.y)
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (100, 10, 255), (*playerPos, player.width, player.height))
    pygame.display.update()


def handle_movement(pressed, player):
    global cameraOffset, playerScreenPos
    player.x += (pressed[pygame.K_d] - pressed[pygame.K_a]) * SPEED
    player.y += (pressed[pygame.K_s] - pressed[pygame.K_w]) * SPEED

def main(): #Main game loop
    player = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
    running = True
    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        draw_screen(player)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        handle_movement(keys_pressed, player)

    
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now, how do you make a camera follow that rectangle? Simple, just add an offset value to everything in the scene. We only have a background and a rectangle in the scene so the above code changes accordingly:

```
#WIN.blit(BACKGROUND, (0, 0))
WIN.blit(BACKGROUND, (0 - cameraOffset[0], 0 - cameraOffset[1]))
#playerPos = (player.x, player.y)
playerPos = (player.x - cameraOffset[0], player.y - cameraOffset[1])
```

All this does is moves the objects by the offset amount. Now the only thing left to figure out is what the offset value needs to be. The offset value should be the player  position - half the screen size. This causes the rectangle to always be in the centre.

```
cameraOffset[0] += player.x - cameraOffset[0] - (SCREEN_W * 0.5)
cameraOffset[1] += player.y - cameraOffset[1] - (SCREEN_H * 0.5)
```

Notice the player position is written out in form of vector. This allows us to add
a delayed following effect by reducing the size of the vector by dividing it by something.

```
delay = 10
cameraOffset[0] += (player.x - cameraOffset[0] - (SCREEN_W * 0.5)) / delay
cameraOffset[1] += (player.y - cameraOffset[1] - (SCREEN_H * 0.5)) / delay
```

Then, based on your needs you can clamp the camera offsets so it won't pan beyond a
certain limit.

```
cameraOffset[0] = max(0, min(cameraOffset[0], MAP_W - SCREEN_W))
cameraOffset[1] = max(0, min(cameraOffset[1], MAP_H - SCREEN_H))
```

Here is the code after camera is added. As you can see, not much has changed.

```
import pygame, os
pygame.init()
   
SPEED = 10

SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H = 800, 600
MAP_W, MAP_H = SCREEN_W*3, SCREEN_H*3
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H))
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
BACKGROUND = pygame.Surface((MAP_W, MAP_H)).convert()

sq = pygame.Surface((50, 50)).convert()
sq.fill((255, 255, 0))
for x in range(27):
    for y in range(18):
        BACKGROUND.blit(sq, (x * 100, y * 100))

delay = 10
cameraOffset = [0 ,0]    
def draw_screen(player):
    WIN.fill((255,255,255))
    WIN.blit(BACKGROUND, (0 - cameraOffset[0], 0 - cameraOffset[1]))
    playerPos = (player.x - cameraOffset[0], player.y - cameraOffset[1])
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (100, 10, 255), (*playerPos, player.width, player.height))
    pygame.display.update()


def handle_movement(pressed, player):
    global cameraOffset, playerScreenPos
    player.x += (pressed[pygame.K_d] - pressed[pygame.K_a]) * SPEED
    player.y += (pressed[pygame.K_s] - pressed[pygame.K_w]) * SPEED

    cameraOffset[0] += (player.x - cameraOffset[0] - (SCREEN_W * 0.5)) / delay
    cameraOffset[1] += (player.y - cameraOffset[1] - (SCREEN_H * 0.5)) / delay

    cameraOffset[0] = max(0, min(cameraOffset[0], MAP_W - SCREEN_W))
    cameraOffset[1] = max(0, min(cameraOffset[1], MAP_H - SCREEN_H))

def main(): #Main game loop
    player = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
    running = True
    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        draw_screen(player)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        handle_movement(keys_pressed, player)

    
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful :D

Comment: @dan_stan_man Your welcome.